# Не могу считать строку в C?

Tags: c, char

учу основы СИ. Пытаюсь считать строку вместе с пробелами, через функцию fgets(). Но функция просто будто не срабатывает и программа не дает ввести строку. Функция gets() уже не работает с новыми стандартами. А функция scanf() считывает только символы до первого пробела. Прошу помочь пожалуйста!

```
char name[12];
printf("Название записи!\n");
fgets(name, 12, stdin);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551751/reading-in-a-string-with-spaces-in-c

Comment: Почему вы решили, что `fgets()` в вашем примере не работает?

Comment: Только что понял, что fgets() не работает в моей созданной функции. А в главной main() функции все работает. Странно

Comment: Вопрос решен!!в

Answer (score 0):

Как вы передавали в функцию значение name? Привел ниже код в котором функция fgets() работает из другой функции.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char* name) {
    printf("Название записи!\n");
    fgets(name, 12, stdin);
    printf("%s",name);
}

int main() {
    char name[12];
    func(name);
    return 0;
}
```